# Discover Web Service in local private network with javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, web-services, networking, service-discovery

I searched for a few options on my issue but couldn't find any useful information unfortunately.

Here is my issue:

Suppose I have 1x computer that runs a rest service on a specific port lets say 5555, running in a private network.

Now I have a frontend/browser application (javascript) that could be opened with a mobile phone or computer. When a device is connected to the same network (suppose wireless) and opens the frontend application it should discover in any way the rest service of the other computer, but I can't find a solution to that challenge.

So I can't find the sevices' ipv4 in the network since the webRTC workaround got smashed. I would have to traverse all possible private ip ranges to find that running service, which seems like an overkill.

Anyone got any idea how to solve this challenge?

Answer (score 1):

Most web apps actually use the port-scan approach, which you are trying to avoid. I could think of some other approaches:

- Have the service also publish an mDNS service under a specific name, e.g. foo.local. Your web app can simply have a static configuration using that hostname. This will, hovewer, require you to be able to control the service and your network/host need to be capable of using mDNS.
- Require the admin of the service to register the local IP adress in a public DNS server. This will require manual config of the URL in the web app, but you can at least avoid dealing with discovering the address.

Comment: I understand. It's so simple for non web applications, since they can just easily determine their own ipv4 and just traverse 254 hosts to see the one that's up. That's probably how printers get detected in a network. I was thinking about getting the Router information so I can narrow down my search since they use pre configured private ip ranges. Another way would be to determine the gateway, then from there traverse 255 hosts. But communicating with the gateway via a browser seems like another challenge. What do you think ?

Comment: I agree, finding the gateway is probably just as difficult as finding out the local subnet. Also, keep in mind that 255 is just one possible subnet size  - the 10.0.0.0/8 subnet is 16mio addresses large.
Maybe you could elaborate more on what you are trying to avoid? e.g. if you want to not have to touch the server id suggest using a DNS server - if you want to avoid changing something in the network you could use the mDNS approach.
Another simple approach would be to have the web server figure out its LAN IP and then send that to an actual DNS server since many DNS hosters have an API.

Comment: @PssstZzz It appears to be possible to use mDNS from the browser: https://soledadpenades.com/posts/2015/front-end-mdns-announcing-and-finding-network-services-with-javascript/ I am curious, let me know if you manage to do it!

Comment: @inf3rno this sounds like an interesting library but given that it relies on a rarely available firefox API it may not be a production-grade approach. What I thought was to not even use the interactive service discovery of mDNS but rather have the server always announce the same domain (e.g. restservice.local) and in your frontend always connect to that hostname. This would work on my hosts that actually use an mDNS daemon for resolving names.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is sort of network scan, which is a security issue if you can do it, though it is usually possible in home networks. I would add a DNS server for that local network and use a local domain name to access the service. I don't know any other standard way to propagate where the service is.

Comment: I see, that would mean to configure the DNS on the router which adds to more work which I was trying to avoid. I'll keep thinking then, thank you for your answer!